# insertAdjacentHTML not working with created element

Tags: javascript, html, insertadjacenthtml

I want to display a `table` after an `h1` with an id of `pageHeading`.
The HTML for the `h1` is hardcoded: `<h1 id="pageHeading">Table</h1>`

```
const pageHeading = document.querySelector("#pageHeading")
```

The table is created with Javascript:

```
const table = document.createElement("table")
table.setAttribute("id", "table")
```

I tried the following:

```
document.body.appendChild(table)
```

This prints the `table` but after the last HTML element on the page.

Then I tried:

tableHeading.appendChild(table)

This prints the `table` but INSIDE the `h1`.

Finally, I tried:

```
pageHeading.insertAdjacentHTML(
  "afterend",
  table
)
```

This doesn't print the table at all. Instead I get (after the `h1`):

```
[object HTMLTableElement]
```

Could this be because I'm  using `.insertAdjacentHTML` on the `table` contents (see full code below)?

```js
const tableHeaders = [{
  titleOne: "Name",
  titleTwo: "Age",
  titleThree: "Nationality",
}, ]

const persons = [{
    name: "James",
    age: "23",
    nationality: "English",
  },

  {
    name: "Isabella",
    age: "21",
    nationality: "Italian",
  },

  {
    name: "Hank",
    age: "25",
    nationality: "American",
  },

  {
    name: "Manon",
    age: "27",
    nationality: "French",
  },
]
const pageHeading = document.querySelector("#pageHeading")

const table = document.createElement("table")
table.setAttribute("id", "table")
/* document.body.appendChild(table) this puts table AFTER the last item in the body <h2>Test</h2> */
/* tableHeading.appendChild(table) this puts table INSIDE <h1 id="tableHeading">Table</h1> */
pageHeading.insertAdjacentHTML(
  "afterend",
  table
) /* this returns: [object HTMLTableElement] */

const headers = tableHeaders.map(header => {
  let ths = `<tr><th>${header.titleOne}</th><th>${header.titleTwo}</th><th>${header.titleThree}</th></tr>`

  table.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", ths)
})

const personDetails = persons.map(person => {
  let tds = `<tr><td>${person.name}</td><td>${person.age}</td><td>${person.nationality}</td></tr>`

  table.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeEnd", tds)
})
```

```html
<h1 id="pageHeading">Table</h1>

<h2>Test</h2>
```

Comment: `insertAdjacentHTML` expects a string value as second parameter, not an HTML element object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of use `insertAdjacentHTML` you need `insertAdjacentElement` because is a element not an html string like:

```js
const tableHeaders = [{
  titleOne: "Name",
  titleTwo: "Age",
  titleThree: "Nationality",
}, ]

const persons = [{
    name: "James",
    age: "23",
    nationality: "English",
  },

  {
    name: "Isabella",
    age: "21",
    nationality: "Italian",
  },

  {
    name: "Hank",
    age: "25",
    nationality: "American",
  },

  {
    name: "Manon",
    age: "27",
    nationality: "French",
  },
]
const pageHeading = document.querySelector("#pageHeading")

const table = document.createElement("table")
table.setAttribute("id", "table")
/* document.body.appendChild(table) this puts table AFTER the last item in the body <h2>Test</h2> */
/* tableHeading.appendChild(table) this puts table INSIDE <h1 id="tableHeading">Table</h1> */

pageHeading.insertAdjacentElement(
  "afterend",
  table
) /* this returns: [object HTMLTableElement] */

const headers = tableHeaders.map(header => {
  let ths = `<tr><th>${header.titleOne}</th><th>${header.titleTwo}</th><th>${header.titleThree}</th></tr>`

  table.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", ths)
})

const personDetails = persons.map(person => {
  let tds = `<tr><td>${person.name}</td><td>${person.age}</td><td>${person.nationality}</td></tr>`

  table.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeEnd", tds)
})
```

```html
<h1 id="pageHeading">Table</h1>

<h2>Test</h2>
```

Reference:

- [insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)
- [insertAdjacentElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement)

Comment: That nailed it! Thanks :)